# Multiple inputs to one string

Tags: c, xcode, input, scanf

I wanted to make a simple program in C that will in while loop get 10 strings user inputs and store them to file food.txt. But there is problem whenever I try to store again user input to variable inputFood. It also send error at 'strcpy(&allFood, inputFood);' Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT. Can anyone help please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int i = 0;

    printf("Hello World!\n");

    char * inputFood;
    char allFood = {0};

    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("/Users/Antonio/Desktop/food.txt", "a");

    while (i < 10){

        i = i + 1;
        scanf("%s", inputFood);
        strcpy(&allFood, inputFood);

    }

    fputs(&allFood, fPointer);
    fclose(fPointer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allocate memory for inputFood, for example 100 chars:

```
inputFood = malloc(100);
```

and make allFood an array, not a char:

```
char allFood[1000];
```

Because of that you will need to use strcat indstead of strcpy like this:

```
strcat(allFood, inputFood);
```

And scan the input food like this:

```
scanf("%99s", inputFood);
```

Comment: `scanf(" %s", inputFood);` is the same meaning as `scanf("%s", inputFood);`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY same meaning, but in practice it is crucial to avoid '\n' which is left in stdin. I recommend using fgets, or other instead of scanf

Comment: @haris When you do strcpy on a string it will always rewrite what you already have, so it is better to use strcat in this case.

Comment: @Igor: i see, thanx.. i changed my answer..   :)

Comment: This is a pointless comment if you know it. It should be indicated field width rather than that.　e.g scanf("%99s", inputFood);

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Please speak so I can understand you. What is a pointless comment?

Comment: _And in scanf add a blank space to consume trailing \n._ this is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62663/discussion-between-igor-and-bluepixy).

Answer (score 0):

```
char * inputFood;
```

You need first allocate memory for it. use `malloc/calloc` memory allocation.

And and

`strcpy` use for copy string not `char`.Also use `fgets` instead `scanf` to overcome buffer overflow issue.

Try something like this:

```
char inputFood[1024];
char allFood[1024];

while (i < 10){

    i = i + 1;

    fgets(inputFood, sizeof(inputFood), stdin);

    if((strlen(allFood)+strlen(inputFood))<1024)
        strncat(allFood, inputFood,strlen(inputFood));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change many things in your program

1)allocate memory for inputFood

```
inputFood = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
```

2)as allFood is already a pointer, dont use `&` in strcpy`, and use`strcat`.

```
 strcat(allFood, inputFood);
```

same goes for `fputs`

```
fputs(allFood, fPointer);
```

3) make `allFood` a character array, as `strcpy` and `fputs` uses character pointers.

```
char allFood[1000];
```